# WPF Application that Listens for Commands Even When not the Active Application

Tags: wpf, command

I would like to configure a WPF application to function in a similar way to SlickRun. I would like to be able to minimize the application to the taskbar, then while in any other program, press a key command (ex: ALT + X) and have my application appear to the user.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [RegisterHotKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309(VS.85).aspx). That works by sending the `WM_HOTKEY` message to the `HWND` you passed in. Since WPF doesn't expose its windows' message loop to developers, you'll probably need to get your hands dirty with some interop and create a message only window to receive the hot key messages.

Comment: This got me on the right track and the following resources look like they will help as well:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/c-using-wpf-and-net-35-how-can-i-register-a-global-hot-key-to-say-ctrlshiftlett

http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/ralph/Blog/archive/2007/02/12/wpf-low-level-keyboard-hook-sample.aspx

http://74.125.155.132/search?q=cache:KDK2eZtejBgJ:blog.280z28.org/archives/2007/03/15/+RegisterHotKey+wpf&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a  (linked to cache as site was down at time of posting)