# Creating KeyBinding in WPF with more than one modifier key

Tags: wpf

The way I created `KeyBinding` was something like:

```
<KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="S" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

But what if I needed two modifier keys? For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The documentation states that you can just separate the modifiers with the `+` character:

```
<KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl+Shift" Key="S" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.modifierkeys.aspx) for the gory details, with the relevant bits extracted below in case the link ever disappears:

---

**XAML**

```
<object property="oneOrMoreModifierKeys"/>
```

**XAML Values**

`oneOrMoreModifierKeys` — One or more modifier keys, defined by the `ModifierKeys` enumeration, delimited with a `+` character.

---

You can also use a gesture on its own rather than a key/modifier combo:

```
<KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+Shift+S" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

as per that same documentation link:

> When defining a KeyBinding in XAML, there are two ways to specify the KeyGesture.
>
> The first way to establish a KeyBinding in XAML is to define the Gesture attribute of the KeyBinding element, which enables a syntax to specify keys and modifiers as a single string, for example "CTRL+P".
>
> The second way is to define the Key attribute and the Modifiers attributes of the KeyBinding element.
>
> Both ways of setting the KeyGesture are equivalent and modify the same underlying object, but there will be a conflict if both are used. In the case when the Key, Modifiers, and the Gesture attributes are all set, the attribute which is defined last will be used for the KeyGesture.

Comment: Microsoft Docs: [XAML Syntax In Detail - Enumeration Attribute Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail): *" KeyBinding.Modifiers ... this property happens to be a special case, because the ModifierKeys enumeration supports its own type converter. The type converter for modifiers uses a plus sign (+) as a delimiter rather than a comma (,). This conversion supports the more traditional syntax to represent key combinations in Microsoft Windows programming, such as "Ctrl+Alt"."*.

Answer (score 16):

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
            Gesture="Ctrl+Shift+S" />
```

See the MSDN documentation, *[KeyBinding Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx)*.

Answer (score 6):

I know the question is for XAML, but here's a sample if you want to do it in code (multiple ModifierKeys can be specified via logical OR):

```
new KeyBinding( SaveCommand, Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is [my code](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_YLl-oZ-4qAd25ITmt1cHhsR3c/edit?pli=1) to implement multiple character shortcut keys, such as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> in WPF MVVM.

Add this to your [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) (attached behavior for the KeyDown event):

```
cb:ShortCutBehavior.Command="{Binding Shortcuts.CmdKeyPressed}"
```

Add this to your view model:

```
ShortCuts Shortcuts = new ShortCuts( this );

//Add Plenty of shortcuts here until your heart is desired

Shortcuts.AddDoubleLetterShortCut( AddOrganization, Key.P, Key.A, ModifierKeys.Alt, true);
Shortcuts.AddSingleLetterShortCut( CmdAddNewAgreement, Key.A, ModifierKeys.Alt);
```

These are two examples of adding shortcuts. The first is a double letter shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> which runs the method AddOrganization() and the second is a single letter shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> which executes the ICommand CmdAddNewAgreemnt.

Both AddDoubleLetterShortCut and AddSingleLetterShortCut are overloaded to accept Actions or ICommands.

This is one of my first attempts at generisizing something, so you can take the idea and make it suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late but here is the simplest and shortest solution.

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.S)
    {
         // Call your method here
    }
}

<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" >
```