# Is there a xamly way to set multiple Modifiers for a KeyBinding?

Tags: .net, wpf, key-bindings

I tried:

```
<KeyBinding Key="S" Modifiers="Control, Shift"/>
```

And

```
<KeyBinding Key="S" Modifiers="Control|Shift"/>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: I thought this looked familiar: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050066/wpf-creating-keybinding-with-more-than-1-modifier-keys/4050175#4050175

Comment: @paxdiablo, oops, didn't notice it. I tried to delete it, but it won't allow me. I hope more users will vote for it to close and clear it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating KeyBinding in WPF with more than one modifier key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050066/creating-keybinding-in-wpf-with-more-than-one-modifier-key)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
<KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl+Shift" Key="S" Command="{Whatever}" />
```

A gesture should also work:

```
<KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+Shift+S" Command="{Whatever}" />
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.modifierkeys.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.modifiers.aspx):

> XAML Values
>
> oneOrMoreModifierKeys One or more
>   modifier keys, defined by the
>   ModifierKeys enumeration, delimited
>   with a "+" character.

So my guess is

```
<KeyBinding Key="S" Modifiers="Control+Shift"/>
```