# WPF KeyBinding with multiple chars

Tags: wpf, key-bindings

I would like to create a KeyBinding in code behind using this combo: Ctrl+Shift+Right+Left, so I did:

```
    KeyBinding b = new KeyBinding()
    {
        Command = SpvCommands.ChangeUser,
        Key = Key.LeftCtrl,
        //Gesture = new KeyGesture(Key.LeftShiftKey);
    };
    InputBindings.Add(b);
```

How to create the gestuyre with multiple combination?

Comment: Have you tried to use `ModifierKeys`?. Here is a neat example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.modifierkeys?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples

Comment: solution for xaml: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050066/creating-keybinding-in-wpf-with-more-than-one-modifier-key In pure c# is probalbly something equivalent where you concatenate the modifiers LittleBit was talking about