# Binding a KeyGesture to a MenuItem inside a ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, contextmenu, commandbinding

I am trying to bind an `InputGesture` to a `RoutedCommand` bound to a `MenuItem` inside a `ContextMenu`.

As shown in image below, I am trying to bind a `KeyGesture` to `Language->English/England` MenuItem where `Language` is a `Button` and `English/England` is a `MenuItem` inside the `ContextMenu` of the `Language` button.

[image: temp]

So far, I have done following:

-> my command

```
public static RoutedCommand SetCultureENCommand = new RoutedCommand("SetCultureENCommand", typeof(ContextMenu));
```

in XAML template, I have following

```
<Button x:Name="btnCulture" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">
<!-- other stuff here -->
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True" />
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="German/Germany" Command="{x:Static DesignerItems:DesignerCanvas.SetCultureDECommand}" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="/myImageDir/de.png" Width="20"/>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="English/England" Command="{x:Static DesignerItems:DesignerCanvas.SetCultureENCommand}" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="/myImageDir/gb.png" Width="20"/>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

I am adding the input gesture to this command as:

```
DesignerCanvas.SetCultureENCommand.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.F11, ModifierKeys.None));
```

and finally, I am registering this as:

```
CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(ContextMenu), new CommandBinding(DesignerCanvas.SetCultureENCommand, SetCultureToEN));
```

I tried to get it done something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682915/defining-menuitem-shortcuts), but it seems the `KeyGesture` is *only* working when I explicitely click the `Language` first and then press the gesture (i.e. after explicitely opening the `ContextMenu`). It is not working when I press the gesture through the `MainWindow` itself (i.e. without explicitely opening the `ContextMenu`).

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you register `KeyBinding` with `InputBindings` of your window?

Comment: @RohitVats No, since it's for a `MenuItem` inside a `ContextMenu`, I am not adding any `Window.CommandBindings` and hence not `Window.InputBindings`. Am I missing something?

Comment: `It is not working when I press the gesture through the MainWindow itself (i.e. without explicitely opening the ContextMenu).` - In case you want it to run directly from MainWindow, you have to register it with your window.

Comment: @RohitVats Ok, I have got it working by adding a `CommandBinding` in `MainWindow` as well (along with the `ContextMenu`) using `this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(DesignerCanvas.SetCultureENCommand, SetCultureEN));` and then 
            `this.InputBindings.Add(new InputBinding(DesignerCanvas.SetCultureENCommand, new KeyGesture(Key.G, ModifierKeys.Control)));`. Although it seems to be working, is there any downside of this i.e. registering a `CommandBinding` with `MainWindow` along with `ContextMenu` that I am missing?