# Keyboard shortcut for wpf menu item

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, menuitem

I am trying to add a keyboard shortcut to the menu item in my xaml code using

```
<MenuItem x:Name="Options" Header="_Options" InputGestureText="Ctrl+O" Click="Options_Click"/>
```

with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

But it is not working - it is not calling the Click option.

Are there any solutions for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682915/defining-menuitem-shortcuts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`InputGestureText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.inputgesturetext(v=vs.110).aspx) is just a text. It does not bind key to `MenuItem`.

> This property does not associate the input gesture with the menu item; it simply adds text to the menu item. The application must handle the user's input to carry out the action

What you can do is create `RoutedUICommand` in your window with assigned input gesture

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly RoutedCommand OptionsCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Options", "OptionsCommand", typeof(MainWindow), new InputGestureCollection(new InputGesture[]
        {
            new KeyGesture(Key.O, ModifierKeys.Control)
        }));

    //...
}
```

and then in XAML bind that command to some method set that command against `MenuItem`. In this case both `InputGestureText` and `Header` will be pulled from `RoutedUICommand` so you don't need to set that against `MenuItem`

```xml
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.OptionsCommand}" Executed="Options_Click"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Menu>
    <!-- -->
    <MenuItem Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.OptionsCommand}"/>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should succeed in this way:
[Defining MenuItem Shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682915/defining-menuitem-shortcuts)
By using KeyBindings:

```
<Window.CommandBindings> <CommandBinding Command="New" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" /> </Window.CommandBindings> <Window.InputBindings> <KeyBinding Key="N" Modifiers="Control" Command="New"/> </Window.InputBindings>
```

Comment: This will only work with common commands, such as, New, Open, Cut, Copy, Paste etc. It does not work with custom user defined commands