# How to show messagebox on f1 keypress WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) window called `MainMenuWindow`. I want to show a `MessageBox` when the user presses F1 on their keyboard, no matter where they are on the window

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Help");
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far.
But I don't know where to reference it or if it's even right. I know how to do it on [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) applications, but cant seem to get it working on [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf).

Comment: You have to reference it in your <Window> XAML object, so `<Window ... KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining MenuItem Shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682915/defining-menuitem-shortcuts)

Comment: You just saved my life, thanks

Answer (score 3):

To specify events, you have to add a `KeyDown` entry to your `Windows`s [xaml](/questions/tagged/xaml) code:

```
<Window xClass="... 
        ...
        ...
        KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), to mark the question as solved