# WPF: Calling a keyboard shortcut for a routed command if you're in a TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox, command

I have a button that has the following commands:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="CommandPretraga"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource CommandPretraga}" Executed="chkPretraga_Click" />
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="ENTER" Command="{StaticResource CommandPretraga}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

The shortcut works if called from most of the window, but if I'm currently in one of my `TextBox` elements, the shortcut doesn't work. I'm guessing that this is because the `TextBox` is registering and processing the ENTER key event, and I tried catching that and calling the same function the shortcut is supposed to call, but that didn't work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is your TextBox multiline? If yes, then there is no clean solution/workaround. I would try removing the multiline property if that is not against the requirements.

Comment: Have you seen this question and answer?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361350/keyboard-shortcuts-in-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept the keystrokes in the PreviewKeyDown event.

If the input is a defined shortcut, raise the corresponding event and set e.Handled to true,
 to prevent further processing of it.