# Adding "close tab" keybinding to WPF TabItem in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, key-bindings

I've implemented this modified TabItem to add a "Close" button to each tab of a WPF TabControl:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281402/Closable-TabItem-in-WPF

Everything works very well, but I cannot figure out for the life of me how to add a KeyBinding for Ctrl+W to serve as an alternate way of closing tabs. I've tried adding to the CloseTab.cs class as well as my main window class with no luck.

I was using this for reference:

[Keyboard shortcuts in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361350/keyboard-shortcuts-in-wpf)

...but I don't really understand how to add the shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't really tested this, but maybe instead of using `InputGestures` (since you can't get that to work I guess), maybe you can alternatively bind to a command and check the `Keyboard` for currently pressed keys?

So inside the xaml where the `ClosableTabItem` is defined:

(you'll need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity`)

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDemo"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

<local:ClosableTabItem Header="TabItem 1">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding KeyDownCommand}"/>
         </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</local:ClosableTabItem>
```

Then the command:

```
private RelayCommand _KeyDownCommand;
public ICommand KeyDownCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (this._KeyDownCommand == null)
            this._KeyDownCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.CheckKeysDown());

        return this._KeyDownCommand;
    }
}
```

And the method:

```
private void CheckKeysDown()
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.W) && ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) > 0))
    {
        // Ctrl + W was pressed
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** To expand on my answer, I found this pretty useful implementation as well:
http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2009/05/mvvm-commandreference-and-keybinding.html

You can use `CommandReference` in the above link's implementation to execute when a `KeyBinding` is satisfied!

**EDIT2:** To do this in the code behind (for dynamically added tab items):

```
System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger trigger = 
    new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger();
trigger.EventName = "KeyDown";
System.Windows.Interactivity.InvokeCommandAction keyDownAction =
    new System.Windows.Interactivity.InvokeCommandAction();
keyDownAction.Command = KeyDownCommand;
trigger.Actions.Add(keyDownAction);
trigger.Attach(yourTabItem);
```

**EDIT3:** Ok, I just got the code myself and played around to figure out a fix for you. The way the `ClosableTabItem` class removes the tab is with the command `StateChange`. And I just added a `KeyBinding` to a tab item I made in the code behind and it worked.

So I did this:

```
ClosableTabItem myTab = new ClosableTabItem();
myTab.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(ClosableTabItem.StateChange, Key.W, ModifierKeys.Control));
```

So when you dynamically create your tabs, add this input binding above and have it hook up to the `StateChange` command. You might have to click the tab or tab area to get it in focus for the key binding to work. I noticed that during my testing.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but how do I add the Interaction.Triggers to my custom TabItem when I'm creating the tabs dynamically in my code?

Comment: @ClairelyClaire - try out my Edit2 and see if that works for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! RelayCommmand doesn't seem to exist, however. I found what appears to be the class used in the MSDN article about RelayCommmand, but nothing happens...

Comment: @ClairelyClaire Ok, check out EDIT3 haha.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly, and with only one line of code, no less! I'm still VERY new to WPF, so I really appreciate the help.