# How to assign a shortcut to a button in MVVMLight

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, mvvm-light

How can I assign the `enter key` to the `on_Click` event in the following code?

To make this clear I want to trigger the code inside the `on_Click()` method when the enter key is pressed.

Again, I'm using the MVVMLight framework.

### ViewModel

```
namespace MyApp.ViewModel
{
    public class AppViewModel : ViewModelBase

    {
        public ICommand clickCommand { get; private set; }

        public AppViewModel()
        {
            clickCommand = new RelayCommand(() => on_Click());
        }

        private void on_Click()
        {      
            // button clicked     
        }
    }
}
```

### XAML

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" 
        Content="Click Me" 
        HorizontalAlignment="right"
        Margin="0,84,72,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="66" Height="25"
        Command="{Binding clickCommand}" Foreground="#FFF2F5FC" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <Button.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF3DA5DB"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361350/keyboard-shortcuts-in-wpf?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks a lot, I ended up using `Nik's` solution from the link `<UserControl.InputBindings> <KeyBinding Gesture="Enter" Command="{Binding someCommand}"/> </UserControl.InputBindings>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great link shared by @shivani. most of the ways are covered there.
One more thing you can do is to set `IsDefault` property of a button.

there is an inbuild feature available that you can set one button as a default to execute click event of that button on enter key press.

SO, you can go with IsDefault as well.

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" 
        Content="Click Me" 
        HorizontalAlignment="right"
        Margin="0,84,72,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="66" Height="25" IsDefault="True"
        Command="{Binding clickCommand}" Foreground="#FFF2F5FC" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
<Button.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF3DA5DB"/>
</Button.Background>
```

Comment: `IsDefault="True"` worked. The only thing I don't like about this method is that the button is in constant focus (flashing all the time).

Comment: @ maulik kansara - Do you know if the fact that the button is in focus all the time is normal behavior when using the `isDefault`?

Comment: I ended up using `<UserControl.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Gesture="Enter" Command="{Binding someCommand}"/>
    </UserControl.InputBindings>`