# Context menu like greenshot

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a program/application to make my job a bit easier. The application is almost done, it works totally fine inside of my wpf project.

I do want to make it a bit more convenient than "Copy selection -> Open app -> Insert text -> start method -> copy output -> insert into another app".

Here i would like it to be a shortcut like "ctrl + alt + shift + c" to copy whatever I've selected (in any application), and then it should start its method immediatly and inserting the output automatically

(Basically whenever a selection is marked, using the shortcut overwrites the selection with the output)

Also note that what I'm looking for something like what greenshot does (where pressing "print scrn" opens it's own context menu)
OR
where it's just a shortcut executing the command (since only one method is needed)

Comment: Google for "sending keypresses to an application" or similar, for starting.

Comment: Is your app a `Windows Forms` based ? if yes, you can use [ProcessCmdKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey) and get the clipboard data using [GetData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getdata?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: For WPF, use the keyboard input binding, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361350/keyboard-shortcuts-in-wpf