# How do i get a System.Windows.Window

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I want to use global hotkeys (one that works outside of the app) and [i found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/c-using-wpf-and-net-3-5-how-can-i-register-a-global-hot-key-to-say-ctrlshift/1960122#1960122)

It looks like i need to initialize it using a System.Windows.Window. But how do i get one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[System.Windows.Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx) is a WPF Window.

If you are doing this with Windows Forms or no form, you can [setup a low-level keyboard hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSLLKeyboardHook.aspx), and trap your hotkey that way.

Comment: Please don't do this.  Keyboard hooks are a fairly unfriendly way to solve a problem for which windows already has a solution.

Comment: Keyboard hooks are the only real way to handle this for supporting hotkeys that work "outside of the app", which the OP requested.  The other solutions require a window handle, typically, which means a form needs to exist, and most only work if the application is active.

Comment: OMG sorry, i accidentally clicked down instead of up. I couldnt change it until i edit your answer. So i edit some whitespace. +1