# Global Hot Key Shortcut for application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I`ve been trying to figure this out, I`m using WPF to build my application. I want to create a shortcut key for the application (CTRL+ALT+3, for example). I`ve tried everything I found over the internet, but with no success.

I want to use a hot key to minimize the application to the tray icon that I will create it later on.

The problem now I can`t figure out how can I do this using the C# WPF on Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/c-using-wpf-and-net-3-5-how-can-i-register-a-global-hot-key-to-say-ctrlshift

Comment: @CodeNaked: The solution in the provided link doesn`t work with me

Comment: @sikas - Which part doesn't work? Seems like the only thing missing from there would be an appropriate routed command. Or are you also asking how to put an icon in the notification area?

Comment: @CodeNaked: This is the error I get from the code over there "The name 'MyAppCommands' does not exist in the current context" ... any ideas about it? I can post my code if it helps

Comment: you asked the same question yesterday. Why didn't you do what was suggested then. Did you try? If so tell us what happened and how you failed.

Comment: @David Heffernan: none of them worked with the WPF. The below answer works but with only one key, CTRL+{Letter|Digit} or ALT+{Letter|Digit} or SHIFT+{Letter|Digit} ... I want to use CTRL+ALT+{Letter|Digit}

Comment: What about [RegisterHotkey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309(VS.85).aspx)?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587425/shortcuts-keys-and-tray-icon

Comment: @Nick: how can I use RegisterHotKey with WPF? I can`t seem to get it work!! and the link u provided is for C++

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in a WPF application. I used some code-behind for the main window.

The creator is:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.AddHandler(Control.PreviewKeyDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(MyPreviewKeyDown), true);
    }
```

The handler begins with:

```
    private void MyPreviewKeyDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyEventArgs ke = e as KeyEventArgs;
        if (ke.Key == Key.Oem5 && ke.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
        {
```

If you need a combination of modifier keys, you can use an expression such as:

```
(int)ke.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == (int)ModifierKeys.Control + (int)ModifierKeys.Alt
```

Comment: How can I set more than one modifier? ex: CTRL+ALT? and what is Oem5 key?

Comment: I have update my answer with code for combinations of modifiers. Oem5 is pipe (|) on my Norwegian keyboard, to the left of the 1-key and above the TAB. Makes it easy to find for my blind users. Might be different in other keyboards.

Comment: Thanks, that solved a small part. The shortcut works when the application is focused. I want to use it when the application is not focused, and I can use RegisterHotKey()!!

Comment: Oh, I thought you just wanted a shortcut key while inside the application. I have never tried to create a shortcut key that works while in other apps. Now I wonder if I should do that for my application....

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HookManager](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx) from codeproject, then use it's KeyDown event.