# opening window when by special shortcut in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, shortcut, tray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I register a global hot key to say CTRL+SHIFT+(LETTER) using WPF and .NET 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/how-can-i-register-a-global-hot-key-to-say-ctrlshiftletter-using-wpf-and-ne)
>   [Set global hotkeys using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450373/set-global-hotkeys-using-c-sharp)

I have a WPF app, by clicking close button or by clicking minimize button it hides but it still remains open in a tray icon . I want to know how can I open the app window with a special shortcut, for example by pressing Shift+Start.
Babylon do the same thing by F10 .

note : I want to do it in WPF 
thanks

Comment: This link helped me and solved my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450373/set-global-hotkeys-using-c-sharp