# Capture Ctrl+V anywhere on WPF Window

Tags: wpf, mvvm, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to implement paste functionality in my application, which means a user can copy a number of files selecting from Windows Explorer and then paste it to the application using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

The problem is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> only works on focused control. The code I used is:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control"
                Key="V"
                Command="{Binding PasteFilesCommand}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

My application is following the MVVM model. How can I capture a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> event when focus is on any control of the application window?

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/48935/620360).

Comment: @LPL - This question has not any clear answer for me. I cant find any answer where MVVM is followed and problem is resolved.

Comment: @DJ Are you trying to paste into a specific control?

Comment: Have a look at [MSDN Commanding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx#simple_command), it has a simple example of binding to [ApplicationCommands.Paste](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.aspx), which is used to provide _a standard set of application related commands_.

Comment: @Bob I have read this article. But it does not solve my problem. In my application you can copy paste files from window explorer. Now if ctrl V pressed on my app. It should be captured. but problem is, if focus is on some child control then how you will fire Application.paste command which is on parent window.