# C# KeyBinding when application on background

Tags: c#, key-bindings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I register a global hot key to say CTRL+SHIFT+(LETTER) using WPF and .NET 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/how-can-i-register-a-global-hot-key-to-say-ctrlshiftletter-using-wpf-and-ne)

I want to create a shortcut for my WPF application.

The application should be invisible most of the time and when Ctrl+N is pressed application should appear.
I tried to do this like that :

```
Mcommand m = new Mcommand();
KeyBinding b = new KeyBinding()
{
  Command = m,
  Modifiers = ModifierKeys.Control,
  Key = Key.Q
 };
```

m executes when an application is visible.
But when application is invisible it doesn't works.
Any idea ?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by invisible?