# Create Key binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to create input binding for Window.

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        SomeCommand = ??? () => OnAction();
    }

    public ICommand SomeCommand { get; private set; }

    public void OnAction()
    {
        SomeControl.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

---

```
<Window>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" Key="F5"></KeyBinding>
    </Window.InputBindings>
</Window>
```

If I init `SomeCommand` with some `CustomCommand : ICommand` it doesn't fire. `SomeCommand` property getter is never called.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

For your case best way used MVVM pattern

XAML:

```
<Window>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" Key="F5"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In your view-model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private ICommand someCommand;
    public ICommand SomeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return someCommand 
                ?? (someCommand = new ActionCommand(() =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("SomeCommand");
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'll need an implementation of `ICommand`.
This simple helpful class.

```
public class ActionCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _action;

    public ActionCommand(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Comment: Is there any quick and simple way run a method `void buttonPress() { MessageBox.Show("It works");` on any particular key combo, e.g. Ctrl+A? I've been searching google for the last 20 minutes, and I can't find a simple example to do just that.

Comment: @MKII do not forgot to add    `DataContext = this;` into `Mainwindow` method

Answer (score 21):

For modifiers (key combinations):

```xaml
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Modifiers="Control" Key="S"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

It might be too late but here is the simplest and shortest solution.

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.S)
    {
         // Call your method here
    }
}

<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" >
```

Comment: It did not work. `e.Key` has `LeftCtrl` or `RightCtrl` because it will be triggered as soon as a Modifier Key is pressed

Comment: Isn't this checking the current state of the pressed keyboard modifier keys, after the actual event you're interested in was triggered? The state of the key-down event should be in the `KeyEventArgs`, including the modifier that were used. `Keyboard` here looks like a (static/local) property or a static class, and I did not check what the APIs look like but this might be the reason why @Zaheer says this did not work.

Comment: hmm.... how about switching the arguments in the `if`? So modifiers only get tested, when `Key == Key.S`

Answer (score 3):

You will have to create your own `Command` implementing `ICommand` interface and initialize `SomeCommand` with the instance of that `Command`.

Now you have to set the `DataContext` of Window to self in order to make the `Command` `Binding` work:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponents();
    DataContext = this;
    SomeCommand = MyCommand() => OnAction();
}
```

OR you will have to update your `Binding` as

```
 <Window>
   <Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SomeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Key="F5"></KeyBinding>
   </Window.InputBindings>
 </Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, a command is not supposed to live in a view; it is supposed to live in a viewmodel. However, on some rare occasions it might make sense to have a command in a view. On such occasions, it is indeed unclear how to connect the key-binding to the command, as the OP found out.

This is how I solved this problem in my project:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MyView"
    (...)
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"
    (...)
    <Grid>
        <Grid.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="R" Command="{Binding ReportCommand, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MyView}}" />
    (...)
```

`ReportCommand` is an `ICommand` in `MyView`, ***not*** in the ViewModel.