# how to fire an event when the TAB key is pressed in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

When i press Tab or shift+tab key the message show, But I to want show this message only when I press tab key not shift+tab key.
How to define this event only when i press Tab key using previewkeydown event in Wpf C# ?

```
private void txtH_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
   {
        MessageBox.Show("Tab");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform a check like

```
if ((!e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift)) 
    && (!e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift)) 
    && e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
```

Or you can do a check like

```
if (!(e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift)
    && e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
```

Comment: I think something is wrong with your brackets in the first if-statement. You've got 7 opening brackets but only 6 closing brackets.

Comment: Removed the extra bracket Nate

Answer (score 1):

WPF is not best used in an event-driven fashion like Winforms. It's best when you use the MVVM pattern in conjunction with Commands to separate out presentation and business logic concerns - this is where WPF is most powerful.

When doing so you can then define `InputBinding` derived XAML elements in your XAML files for your View and specify a `Command` to run using the `Command` attribute which is in your ViewModel.

e.g.

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding ShowMessageCommand}" Key="Tab" />
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding ShowMessageCommand}" Modifiers="Shift" Key="Tab" />
```

Comment: Workout and a clear explanation can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697106/create-key-binding-in-wpf