# KeyDown Events in WPF Application only work with Focus

Tags: c#, wpf, keydown

I have a calculator with a WPF Interface, and there is a grid containing most of the buttons. I want these buttons to react to, say, the NumPad keys, among others. I created **KeyDown Events** for all of them, but this only works when the button whose key I press is currently focused. I read about the **KeyPreview property**, but that only exists for Windows Forms, correct? I feel like I just need to change a property of my `ButtonGrid`, but I can't figure it out.
Relatively new to programming by the way.

**Edit:** This is one of the methods, how would a generic method look like? OnlyDigitsInTextBox is a custom method consisting of the .AppendText Extension method.

```
private void Button6_Key(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.NumPad6)
        {
            OnlyDigitsInTextBox("6");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to animate the buttons to reflect the key press or are you okay just by getting the input from the keyboard? If latter then you can just wire the KeyDown/KeyUp events on the main window and set your controls Focusable=false. If you need to animate then you need more work.

Comment: No animation needed, I'll try that, thanks, but how are the buttons recognized by calling the KeyDown Event in the MainWindow?

Comment: You should just have a generic event handler that checks what key was pressed and from there forward to the same function that is called by your button clicks.

Comment: Alternatively you could use KeyBindings instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697106/create-key-binding-in-wpf

Comment: @tweedledum11 You get the key from the KeyEventArgs parameter, like e.Key.

Comment: I tried KeyBindings before and couldn't get it to work, so I used the KeyDown event. How would a generic event handler for the KeyDownEvent look like? I still need to associate each Button with a specific key? I obviously can't put every KeyDownEvent as a property of the MainWindow.

Comment: By the way, the `Preview<...>` events are available in WPF too.

Comment: I edited my question to show my KeyDown Event methods.

Answer (score 2):

Best approach would be to use Custom Commands with KeyBindings.

[WPF Custom Commands](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFCustomCommands.aspx)

[WPF KeyBindings](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFKeyBindings.aspx)

Comment: Linking articles is not exactly an answer.

Comment: Links are for help only.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work now with an EventHandler using **switch case** for every possible button, and putting that EventHandler up as a property of the MainWindow, setting the Focusable property of all buttons to False. This is probably far from ideal, but it works for now, so thanks everybody!