# Attempting to execute method using KeyBinding

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to execute a method when the user presses ctrl + Tab. If there is more than one window (App.Current.Windows >1), then CanExecute should be true, otherwise false.

 
All posts I read so far suggest I need to write a subclass for ICommand and a ViewModel which is basically the "link" between the UI and tge custom command. I've read some examples 
[of how to create bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697106/create-key-binding-in-wpf)
and because I didn't get this I tried to
[learn more about MVVM](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/100175/%2fArticles%2f100175%2fModel-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained)
but I'm afraid I'm still feeling clueless.

---

What would an example checking for more than one window open and executing a method SomeMethod if CanExecute was true look like? Where would I place what? I'm sorry, but I searched and tried all day - and still feel clueless. 

Any examples or pointers to good explanations?

Comment: In WPF the windows are Views, which are binded to View Models (or VMs). If you create a tree of View Models - parent object with child objects, where each of the children has a View binded to it, then the child VMs updated the parent VM, the parent VM could aggregate the state (e.g. have a properties of number of children), which could be used be the commands on the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it

in Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="ExecuteCommand" Text="ExecuteCommand" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Tab" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{StaticResource ExecuteCommand}" />
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource ExecuteCommand}" CanExecute="ExecuteCommand_CanExecute" Executed="ExecuteCommand_Executed"  />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In Code Behind:

```
    private void ExecuteCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = App.Current.Windows.Count > 1;
    }

    private void ExecuteCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! This looks good and I understand it. This will certainly do.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the feeling that you are new to WPF and MVVM, Although it's recommended, you don't have to use MVVM with WPF. You can do the same thing by event handlers.

Here is something you might want to try:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        KeyUp += MainWindow_KeyUp;
    }

    private void MainWindow_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(App.Current.Windows.Count.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to MVVM and relatively new to WPF. The reason why I tried KeyBinding was that other posts suggested you cannot keep track of key + modifier key (or would have to do so by altering a boolean value.) This sounded unelegant, so I tried to get KeyBindings and MVVM to work, it feels like it's still over my head, though.

Comment: Okay, can you help me understand why can't you use the code above?

Comment: Well, currently I'm encountering the problem that it always executes, even in alt-tab, shift-tab, etc. Trying to fix that like this: if((e.key == Key.Tab && KeyBoard.IsKeyDown(LeftCtrl)) || (e.key == Key.Tab && KeyBoard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)))

Comment: I might have to track the state of the modifier keys separately though - at least that's what some posts suggested. We'll see...

Comment: Turns out it was me forgetting an if-clause... I swear, sometimes I feel incredibly stupid.

Comment: @TimB no worries, happens to us all haha