# How to Set focus on datagrid after any operation on window WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a window which consist 3 user controls. 3rd user control consist a `datagrid` which filled up when a browse button is clicked and file is open in 1st user control. 2nd user control consist some filter operation controls over `datagrid`.

What I need is to bind some hotkeys in 3rd user controls.
Problem - when I browse a file in 1st user control focus is not set to `datagrid` so hot keys not worked. If I use any filer operation in 2nd user control than also focus removed from `datagrid` and keys will not work.
What should I do so that when there is file open and any filer operation performed then focus should be on `datagrid` so that hot key will work?

Comment: Attach the current code if you can, it's easier then to give some tailored advice. And have you tried calling `datagrid.Focus()` at the end of each event handler for the 1st and the 2nd user control? Another solution would be attaching the _key pressed_ event handler to the window and not to the datagrid itself.

Comment: Firstly, User Controls are overkill and 9 times out of 10 are not needed. You can attach Key Bindings in xaml [Here is a SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19702668/2029607) as always use MvvM. Looking at the lack of code I am assuming there is no MvvM. To manage focus use FocusManager [here is another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21891179/2029607). Good luck