# WPF detect key sequence

Tags: wpf, visibility, keycode

I would like to hide a groupox from my WPF app and to manually enable it when I need it via a keypress code when app is active(not minimized)

this example works sometimes with just one keypress, but I need a sequence

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        if (e.Key == Key.B)
        {
            bdgb.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered "hotkey" or inputbinding with ctrl or alt + one letter as a keychord? This would be more usual than typing some magic string.

Comment: I would like it to be without any other key being held

Comment: You can use a keybinding with function keys. Pressing a sequence of just letters is a bad idea. Also. Active has a specific meaning as in focussed. It only works when you click your window because if you go click a different window then your app is not active. Only one thing can have focus.

Comment: Ok, let's say I'd go for a Ctrl+A combo instead of a sequence...how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example override the `OnPreviewKeyDown` method of your window, e.g.:

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    if (e.Key == Key.B)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: updated the code. When pressing B , the a groupbox named bdgb should become visible.

Comment: it only works when click some random portions of the UI ,while spamming "B" in the same time...

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify your question accordingly.

Comment: I believe it happens because I'm not applying the code the MainWindow itself, but to a page within it. The hidden control that I need to uncover is in a page contained in the MainWindow. I would have put the code in the MW, but I don't know how to access the control from there

Comment: That's a different topic, isn't it?. Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Your original question was about how to handle key presses.

Answer (score 0):

On what did you put the handler? Only currently focused element gets the notification, and if it is not handled, it goes up the tree.

You need to put it in the most top UIElement, which means your window.

Or, you can do it in a moer MVVMy WPF style, by creating a command binding to the key and having a property on your VM `GroupBoxVisible`, set it to "True" and have binding to the `GroupBox.Visibillity`.

Moer details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697106/create-key-binding-in-wpf)