# WPF access a page control from MainWindow class

Tags: wpf, class, mainwindow

I have created a WPF app that has navigation between two pages.
I want a control(a groupbox) from one of the pages to be hidden by default and to be able to enable it when pressing a keycombo.
Home1 is the name of the page and bgdb is the name of the groupbox.
Home1_Loaded is hooked up to the page loading inside a frame in MainWindow

```
public void Home1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bdgb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

What modifications need to be done so I can access bgdb from MainWindow class and unhide it via a keycombo (ex Ctrl+B) ?
this is the code for mainwindow loading the homepage by default

```
private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Main.Content = new home();
    Main.Navigate(new Uri("home.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

Comment: Look here. This will help you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/how-can-i-register-a-global-hot-key-to-say-ctrlshiftletter-using-wpf-and-ne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are hosting the `Page` in a `Frame` element in the `MainWindow`, you could cast the `Content` property of the `Frame` to `Home1` and then access any of its members, e.g.:

```
Home1 home1 = e.Content as Home1;
if (home1 != null)
    home1.bdgb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Frame x:Name="frame" />
```

You could for example handle the `Navigated` event for the `Frame`:

```
private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Main.Content = new home();
    Main.Navigated += Main_Navigated;
    Main.Navigate(new Uri("home.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}

private void Main_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    home home1 = Main.Content as home;
    if (home1 != null)
        home1.bdgb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    Main.Navigated -= Main_Navigated;
}
```

Comment: I have edited a bit the question to include the pageloading code.where would the first part of the code go ?

Comment: @erma86: So the `Frame` is named `Main`? See my edit.

Comment: Yes.Frame is named Main. Used the edited code but:The type or namespace name 'Home' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) error x2

Comment: @erma86: `Home1` is the name of your `Page` class where the `GroupBox` is defined. It should probably be `home` in your case. See my edit.

Comment: ok . got it, the class was 'home' in my case. And now for the "reveal" of the hidden object, i could go with protected override bit from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54111705/wpf-detect-key-sequence ?

Comment: @erma86: Please don't ask additional questions in the comments field. Ask a new question if you have another issue. This question was about how to access the page from the window.

Comment: @erma86: No, it is not. You should only ask one question per thread.