# Is there a function to minimize and maximize my programm with a key shortcut ? c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

```
        KeyBinding KeyBinding = new KeyBinding(
        ApplicationCommands.Open,
        Key.R,
        ModifierKeys.Control);

        this.InputBindings.Add(KeyBinding);
```

This is all i got till now for my Shortcut. I am new to C# WPF .

Comment: There are no implemented commands like `ApplicationCommands.Open` in framework to minimize/maximize the window. You have to implement your own.

Comment: Windows natively supports Winodws + Arrow Down
and Alt + Tab to get back in. This is not WPF specific.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935/how-can-i-register-a-global-hot-key-to-say-ctrlshiftletter-using-wpf-and-ne